# Notifications for changes in user data in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I created a subscription in Azure AD for receiving notification when a user is deleted. But I'm not receiving any notifications when I delete or update a user.
I got 201 code, so every thing is ok.
I've been waiting for more than 24 hours !

```js
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity",
    "id": "5bfc6bc2-a4bd-4e03-b420-7f5f72158dab",
    "resource": "users",
    "applicationId": "4547857b-a6ce-424f-8f71-d1f0c8050c59",
    "changeType": "updated,deleted",
    "clientState": null,
    "notificationUrl": "https://8ffa2519154d.ngrok.io/azure/notifications",
    "expirationDateTime": "2020-09-16T11:05:00Z",
    "creatorId": "78f2eabd-f0a5-4350-b541-ef9edb47ae80",
    "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}
```

Comment: Did your endpoint validate the webhook registration? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#creating-a-subscription

Comment: yes, and returned the token with response code 200

Comment: Make sure you have enabled Webhook and make sure that the Webhook is within the use date.

Comment: @CarlZhao yes I didn't enable Webhook ! how can I do it ?

Comment: @MehdiJomaa  You can enable it when you create it  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks#create-a-webhook

Comment: @CarlZhao I created a Webhook but the problem persists